# How to enable indexing in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, indexing

I disabled indexing to get speed back, it worked! Now I upgraded my RAM from 4gb to 8gb and would like to give it a try again.

I used this code in terminal the 1st time:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable 1
```

I tried this code and restarted, didn't work:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexEnable 1
```

Anyone know another command?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Defaults are a name-value store per domain. The setting's domain here is `com.apple.dt.Xcode`. The setting's name is `IDEIndexDisable`. You set this to **1**. To undo this, you need to remove the setting, not add another one with a different name.

Based on the command you entered the first time, use this:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEIndexDisable
```

While you're at it, you should delete the key you added as well:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEIndexEnable
```

(Note that `com.apple.dt.XCode` with the capital C is a past mistake, likely yours, that shouldn't really matter on case insensitive file systems like Mac OS X uses by default.)

Comment: Yeah, it will. The other part of the answer concerns deleting the extra (and incorrect) key that was added by the asker.

Comment: Great @StevenFisher This save me lots of time :) Thanks

Comment: didn't work for me with xcode 8.2.1 ... it still keeps indexing ... you're using Xcode, another answer is with XCode ... which one to use?

Comment: Application identifier is case insensitive. You can use xcode, Xcode or XCode with the same result.

Comment: Application identifiers are bundle identifiers, which means they ARE case sensitive, but it is not quite that simple because macOS is usually run on a case insensitive file system. Here, the bundle identifier is used primarily as a file name. If the bundle identifier is only ever handled at the file system level they'd be effectively case insensitive, but you should NOT rely on that.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of deleting the written setting, just toggling its value worked for me.
Enter the following in a terminal window:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable 0
```

Comment: It will, but the setting isn't there by default. There's no reason to keep it around instead of deleting it.

Comment: No this isn't working for me any way so @StevenFisher 's answer is perfect and recommended by me

Comment: I spent over an hour today searching for the solution here, this finally works - thank you!