# Xcode 4 indexing taking too much time

Tags: xcode

I am using latest xcode 4.2 and whenever I open existing project, it is going for indexing files, I am not able to stop it and my Macbook is going to busy with processing indexing... how can I stop it or let me know if any setting where we can avoid and get the all features like smart editor.

Thanks
Manu

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328041/how-to-enable-indexing-in-xcode-4) question out...i think it will help. if not, you could try to disable ARC.