# Xcode assistant editor won't show some of the code

Tags: xcode, swift, crash, editor, assistant

First of all, I would like you to know that the class IS set to the correct file in each `ViewController` - I know that because it did work before, but then I got a "crash" in Xcode that blinked quickly without me being able to read it before it went off again.

**MY PROBLEM IS**:

I have a lot of `ViewControllers` in my Xcode, everything was working fine, I was making some more features to the `ViewControllers`.

Then I got the "crash" as mentioned above, and it would not show any of the files/classes related to their `ViewController` in assistant editor.

Assistant editor just said: No Assistant Results. Then I read that I could just show the files inside my XCode project and delete `project.xcworkplace` and xcuserdata. And I thought it worked at first, but it did not work on every viewcontroller unfortunately - only on some of them.

Now, I still have plenty of `ViewControllers` left to edit that aren't working, and I would hate if I had to recreate every single one.

Does anyone have a better solution to this? I really hope you do :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you set `Automatic` not `Manual`.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There was some related answer but I can't find it. Anyhow: what I do to fix it is to uncheck the Target Membership in the File Inspector for the XIB and then turn it on again. That fixes the issue (in most cases) for me.

Also try restarting/clearing the different caches of XCode.

Comment: Yes, target membership was the issue. This fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was similarly not able to view code/classes relating to the View Controller. In my particular case, it appears i might have caused the issue- I turned OFF Indexing because Xcode was running terribly slow and around that time I started getting the issue and the message “No assistant results”.

To resolve this in my case, I turned indexing back ON and set the Assistant editor to “Automatic”.

To turn Indexing On or Off, open up the Terminal using either of the below commands-

Turn Indexing OFF:
defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable 1

Turn Indexing ON :
defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable 0

From accepted answer regarding Indexing: [Stopping xcode from indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959709/stopping-xcode-from-indexing)

Answer (score 0):

xcode 9.0

1. Open project.
2. Click on "Show the assistant editor".(top right side middle button - circle shape)
3. Code was show after do second step.

Answer (score 0):

I cloned a project and found that I have the same problem. But **all I did to fix it was to just sign the app at Signing and Capabilities** and the option for the right View Controller pops up in the top bar of the Assisntant in my View