# Xcode code sense symbol not found Indexing not working. Xcode repair tools command line tools

Tags: xcode, xcode7.1, xcode-command-line-tools

I am using Xcode 7.1 and macOS Sierra. My Xcode is not indexing my project, I also enable indexing through terminal. Indexing is not working in in any of the Xcode version of my mac machine, because of this, I am not able to use Xcode code sense functionality. It gave me the error:

> Symbol not found

I cleaned derived data and all, but still its not working.

I want to enable Xcode CMD-Click code sense functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems that your Xcode doesn't Pre build your code and it also seems that your Xcode indexing is disabled.

From terminal please write an command to enable Indexing
and restart you machine and XCode.

To enable Indexing Go to -->
[How to enable indexing in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328041/how-to-enable-indexing-in-xcode)

Enjoy